# Create a bipartite graph with igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, bipartite

I'm trying to create a bipartite graph with the following matrix :

```
    G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6
virus1  0   1   1   0   1   0
virus2  1   1   0   0   0   0
virus3  0   1   0   0   0   0
virus4  1   0   0   0   0   0
virus5  0   1   0   1   0   1
virus6  1   1   0   1   0   0
```

Here is the code I use for the moment :

```
install.packages("igraph")
library(igraph)
matrice = read.table("C:/Users/loisv/Desktop/test4.txt",sep="\t", row.names=NULL,header=TRUE)
net2 <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(matrice)
plot(net2, vertex.size=7, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

My code take into account as header my first line but not my first column (virus1, virus2 ...)

[The dataframe containing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA6U2.png)

Here is the graph I'm getting for the moment : 
[The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYZH.png)

Can you help me please ?

Comment: remove the `row.names=NULL` from `read.table`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not change anything ...

Comment: from your data image, you are still having an error with the row.names. If done correctly it should not have a column header. Can you edit your question with your updated code to read in the data please.

Comment: you may need to be explicit: `row.names=1` to force the first column to be rownames.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much !